# Why is spring-hadoop end-of-lifed and is there a successor?

Tags: java, spring, hadoop, spring-data-hadoop

According to the `README` in [spring-hadoop](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-hadoop), the project has reached an End-Of-Life:

> NOTICE: The Spring for Apache Hadoop project has reached End-Of-Life
> status on April 5th, 2019. The final Spring for Apache Hadoop 2.5.0
> release was built using Apache Hadoop version 2.7.3 and no new
> releases are planned.

I assumed the project would be continued under a different name, or perhaps a completely new project in the Springframework family would succeed it, but I haven't been able to find any further details and their Github issue tracker is disabled.

Could anybody please provide some more details and explain what else should be used instead? Thanks!

Comment: I don't think this is really suitable question for Stack Overflow, but have you looked at the announcement [Spring for Apache Hadoop project End-Of-Life announcement](https://spring.io/blog/2018/04/05/spring-for-apache-hadoop-project-end-of-life-announcement)